# Java program not asking for input when ran, what did I do wrong?

Tags: java

I'm trying to create a code where the user inputs a number, and the program returns whether the number is prime or not. This is my first code in Java, so I'm still learning! The code compiles but when I run it, it doesn't have an option to input.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Prime {
    public void main(String[] args) 
{
        Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in); 
        int number = reader.nextInt();
        if (isPrime(number) == true)
        {
            System.out.println(number+"is a prime number");
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.print(number+"is not a prime number");
        }
    }

    public boolean isPrime(int number)
    {
        int counter = 0;
        boolean result = true;
        for (int n = 2; n <= 9; n++) {
            if (number % n == 0 && n != number) {
                counter = 1;
            } else {
                counter = 2;
            }
            if (counter == 1){
                result = true;
            }
            else result = false;
        }
            return (result);
    }
}
```

Comment: This code *does* wait for user input. Are you using Eclipse? There are issues sometimes with that IDE.

Comment: How are you running your code?

Answer (score 4):

The issue here is regarding the main method which is missing the **static** keyword, so there is no app entry without that.

Please change the main method from

```
public void main(String[] args)
```

To

```
public static void main(String[] args)
```

Also, add **static** to the isPrime method in order to everything work.

Answer (score 0):

This problem arised because of no Entry point was found by the java compiler

**Code Snippet**
[Run Code Here](https://ideone.com/2wHEdT)

```
import java.util.Scanner;

   public  class Prime {
        public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
            Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in); 
            int number = reader.nextInt();
            if (isPrime(number) == true)
            {
                System.out.println(number+"is a prime number");
            }
            else
            {
                System.out.print(number+"is not a prime number");
            }
        }

       static public boolean isPrime(int number)
        {
            int counter = 0;
            boolean result = true;
            for (int n = 2; n <= 9; n++) {
                if (number % n == 0 && n != number) {
                    counter = 1;
                } else {
                    counter = 2;
                }
                if (counter == 1){
                    result = true;
                }
                else result = false;
            }
                return (result);
        }
    }
```